# Rails query with 'joins' and 'sum"'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have model Grain_input with "weight_fact" field

```
class GrainInput < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :movements, as: :sourceable    
end
```

and model Movement with "amount" field

```
class Movement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sourceable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :targetable, polymorphic: true
end
```

grain_input has many movements. For example, part of grain_input from storage to equipment, other part elsewhere.
I need to get all grain_inputs, that still present at storage. 
Scope for this:

```
      scope :at_storage, -> { 
            joins(:movements).
            group("grain_inputs.id").
            having("sum(movements.amount) < grain_inputs.weight_fact") }
```

This scope works, but return only grain_inputs, that have movements. 
But I need grain_inputs, that has no movements too.

Please, help to fix scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can try left join

```
      scope :at_storage, -> { 
        joins("LEFT JOIN `movements` ON movements.grain_input_id = grain_inputs.id" ).
        group("grain_inputs.id").
        having("sum(movements.amount) < grain_inputs.weight_fact") }
```

Comment: Tnx for your reply, but doesn't work - result the same.